# Beta as an exponent?

Tags: econometrics

Can **beta** be an exponent within a function prior to taking the log of that function to arrive at a simple, log-linear estimation equation?

I am curious because I found an equation that had beta as an exponent on **page 7** of this article by Lee Branstetter(2004): http://bit.ly/1OGSFx9 titled: *Is Foreign Direct Investment a Channel of Knowledge Spillovers? Evidence from Japan’s FDI in the United States*

I believe there this is not out-of-order. I am however, seeking an explanation to the equation.

I have tried to check different sources and the closest explanation is that the function is a linear-log function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a structural paper. The authors are not "*deriving*" a log-linear relationship from a model, which they then proceed to estimate. They rather start by postulat the relationship:

> Let $C^J_{it}$ be the number of citations made by the patent
>   applications Japanese firm i filed in year t to the cumulated stock of
>   bindigenousQ U.S.-invented patents granted as of year $t$. I can then
>   write the log of $C^J_{it}$ as a simple log-linear function of several
>   other observables
>
> $$ c^J_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 p_{it} + \beta_2 FDI_{it} + \gamma_i +
> > \alpha_t + \epsilon_{it}$$

which is their equation (1).

Comment: Thanks @Foobar but: 
(1) how is postulating different from estimating a model and;
(2) under what circumstances would each be more suitable. 
I ask because I believe both requires making assumptions and testing those assumptions with an equation. Thanks.